# angular Local storage data is undefined in online Event of navigator

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am adding Angular Local storage from a file name last.js using this code

```
 $localStorage.myData = [];
 $localStorage.myData.push({
name; "faizan",
uni: "FUSSAT"
})
alert($localStorage.myData);//it is showing data as expected!!!
```

now on online event i am doing this to access it but unfortunately it is undefined .. I guess it is making new $localStorage

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
 window.addEventListener('online', function updateOnlineStatus($localStorage) {
      alert("online fired")//it is run when online navigatior
      alert($localStorage.myData)//it is undefined..why??????????????????????????
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument passed to the event handler is an event object, not a localStorage object https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Online_and_offline_events you will have to put your event listener inside an Angular service or controller in order to be able to access your $localStorage object.

Comment: if i register event listner in a ctrl so will this run every time when the event call?

Comment: i have added to my controller but it not working now

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?